# Stubbing functions which are in closure in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, sinon

I'm writing code on TypeScript. Here is my code snippet:

```
module mymodule {

    export function internalFunc() {
        return 1;
    }

    export function externalFunc() {
        return internalFunc() + 1;
    }
}
```

Which will be compiled to this JS:

```
var mymodule;
(function (mymodule) {
    function internalFunc() {
        return 1;
    }
    mymodule.internalFunc = internalFunc;
    function externalFunc() {
        return internalFunc() + 1;
    }
    mymodule.externalFunc = externalFunc;
})(mymodule || (mymodule = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=file1.js.map
```

I need to test `externalFunc` with stubbing `internalFunc` (for example, it should return 7). But reference to `internalFunc` is in closure, I can change `mymodule.internalFunc`, but  `externalFunc` will use old `internalFunc`. I tried to use `sinon.stub(mymodule, 'internalFunc', function() {return 7})`, but it didn't work either. Can I properly stub my function?

Comment: The "unit" you should be testing at this point is probably your entire module.  You don't need to unit test at the individual function level.

Comment: "*I can change mymodule.internalFunc, but externalFunc will use old internalFunc*" - That doesn't sound correct. Could you detail how you tried this in your test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reference it via `mymodule.internalFunc() + 1` instead of `internalFunc() + 1`:

```
module mymodule {
    export function internalFunc() {
        return 1;
    }

    export function externalFunc() {
        return mymodule.internalFunc() + 1;
    }
}

mymodule.internalFunc = () => 7;
console.log(mymodule.externalFunc()); // 8
```

Now you should be able to use it in the way you described (though I'm not familiar with sinon):

```
sinon.stub(mymodule, 'internalFunc', () => 7);
assertEquals(8, mymodule.externalFunc());
```